# Inheritance Error "Base Class Unidentified"

Tags: c++

I have a State class that is fully implemented as outlined below. I also have a PlayState class that inherits the State class, it too is fully implemented. My compile error is "playstate.h(6): error C2504: 'State' : base class undefined"
I have checked their order in Global.h, State.h appears before PlayState.h

**CODE:**
STATE.H

```
#pragma once

  #include "Global.h"

class State
{
   public:
State(void);
virtual ~State(void);

virtual void Input(INPUTDATA* InputData);
virtual void Logic(OBJECT go[], INPUTDATA* InputData);
virtual void Render(OBJECT go[]);
virtual void InitGame(OBJECT go[]);
virtual void LoadGraphics(void);

void Toggle();
bool IsEnabled();

  private:
bool isEnabled;

 };
```

PlayState.h

```
#include "Global.h"

 class PlayState : public State
 {
  private:
#define UPDATESPEED 1000    // milliseconds between each update

// global variables
float camXAngle;
float camYAngle;
float camZoom;
int updatetime;
bool gameover;
float runspeed;
D3DLIGHT9 light;

SPRITE graphics;
SPRITE particleTexture;
MODEL terrain[2];
MODEL sky;

 public:
PlayState();
~PlayState();

void Input(INPUTDATA* InputData);
void Logic(OBJECT go[], INPUTDATA* InputData);
void Render(OBJECT go[]);
void InitGame(OBJECT go[]);
void LoadGraphics(void);
 };
```

Thanks

Comment: @user692270: Can you show what your `Global.h` looks like?

Comment: You mean that you include "PlayState.h" into "Global.h" and at the same time include "Global.h" to "PlayState.h"?

Comment: @user692270: Right. You have to show "Global.h" contents and your compiled *.cpp file contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If some *.cpp includes "State.h" without "Global.h" somewhere before it then you will have the error that you've posted.

Because when "State.h" includes "Global.h" then "Global.h" does not include "State.h" (because of `#pragma once`) but it includes "PlayState.h" so in the end you have "PlayState.h" included before `class State` is defined.

Just don't make such weird circular inclusions.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Global.h` already includes `State.h` and `PlayState.h` and in the order that `State.h` is placed before `PlayState.h`, then there is no reason to get the particular error(for the source code you have posted), unless except you are making some silly typo like missing a caps in State. Please check for typos!  or there might be another reason to the problem.

You are building a circular dependency of includes, which should be avoided.
A simple solution might be to not include both includes, `State.h` and `PlayState.h` in `Global.h`. 
Just include `State.h` inside `PlayState.h` and it should be fine. `Global.h` wont build up any circular dependencies that way.

Comment: "here is no reason to get the error" Not true. If some *.cpp includes "State.h" without "Global.h" somewhere before it then you will have the exact same error that poster has.

Comment: @Serge Dundich: True, I should say in the source code OP has posted. I will make that modification, though the edited suggestion might solve his issue.

Comment: Yes. Circular inclusions is evil to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma once

#include "Global.h"

 class PlayState : public State
```

What is "State"? That is what the compiler is complaining about.

You can't inherit from a class that has not been fully defined. Looking at the file PlayState.h, nowhere do you specify the State class.

CORRECTED CODE:

```
  #pragma once

#include "State.h"
 class PlayState : public State
```

Comment: Whilst not included in the original questions code, user692270 did seem to state that  in 'global.h', it included both State.h & PlayState.h, in the right order.  Why does it make any difference if it's included again in the PlayState.h?  Is it impacted by the pragma once?

Comment: your corrected code corrects nothing in this situation. You would still have the same error.